# Jetpack Compose imageVector : how do I able to use the Social vector from google fonts

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

I tried to import the icon provided by Google Font according to the prompts of Google Font, but I found that I could not import the icon of cake into my EditText. Can you please take a look what is going on ?Thank you so much !

```
@Composable
fun ShowTextField(context:Context){
  
    var text by remember {
        mutableStateOf("")
    }
    TextField(value = text ,
        onValueChange = {text = it},text
        label = { Text(text = "birthday")},
        leadingIcon = @Composable{
            
            Image(
                imageVector = Icons.Filled.Cake,
                contentDescription = "cake",
                modifier = Modifier.clickable { 
                    Toast.makeText(
                        context,
                        "Your Birthday：${text}",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                    ).show()
                }
            )
        }
    )
}
```

[Cake Google Font](https://fonts.google.com/icons?selected=Material%20Icons&icon.query=cake)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. As far as I know, you need to download it as .svg file and import into the drawable folder as vector asset before you use it,
2. after you import it, in your code you should use Icon(), not Image() and instead of imageVector just use `painterResource(R.drawable.cake)`

( of course if you named your asset as "cake" ;) )

```
@Composable
fun ShowTextField(context:MainActivity){

    var text by remember {
        mutableStateOf("")
    }

    TextField(value = text,
        onValueChange = {text = it},
        label = { Text(text = "birthday")},
        leadingIcon = @Composable{

            Icon(
                painterResource(R.drawable.cake),
                contentDescription = "cake",
                modifier = Modifier.clickable {
                    Toast.makeText(
                        context,
                        "Your Birthday：${text}",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                    ).show()
                }
            )
        }
    )

}
```

Comment: Awesome answer ! Thank you so much my friend !

Comment: also, just a suggestion, you could change the "context: MainActivity" into "context:Context" it may be confusing for some people why you are passing an [activity](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity) named as [Context](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Context)

Comment: Great suggetion,I will modify it !Thank you so much !